# Cordova app no XHRs requests work in IOS

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova

I have a Cordova app. It uses a standard jquery AJAX call to pull some data. It doesn't work on the IOS device or in the emulator. Debugging within the emulator showed no XHRs calls, but no errors are logged either.

```
$.ajax({
    url : serverURL,
    type : 'GET',
    username : email,
    password : password,
    error : function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    success : function (rows) {
        console.log(rows);
    }
});
```

Works in Android. I have used the url in a browser in the emulator and on the device and it works.

Comment: if it works on android it might be the whitelist, but it's strange that it doesn't fire the error. Can you post your config.xml? cordova version? the url is an external server or your development machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be related to this;

```
username : email,
```

had to be replaced with;

```
username : encodeURIComponent(email),
```

IOS couldn't handle '@' in the username, once encoded it worked fine.